# Annoying DateTime issue ([dateStepNotStep] => The input is not a valid step ) when updating record

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm developing a page with Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine in a Lamp Server. I'm having a hard time to resolve this annoying problem. I have a entity:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
* Usuarios
*
* @ORM\Table(name="usuarios", indexes=    {@ORM\Index(name="fk_usuarios_idTipo_idx", columns={"idTipo"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Usuarios
{

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dataCriacao", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
private $datacriacao;

/**
 * Set datacriacao
 *
 * @param \DateTime $datacriacao
 *
 * @return Usuarios
 */
public function setDatacriacao($datacriacao)
{
    $this->datacriacao = $datacriacao;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get datacriacao
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDatacriacao()
{
    return $this->datacriacao;
}

    public function exchangeArray($data = array())
{
    $this->datacriacao      =       isset($data['datacriacao'])     ?       $data['datacriacao']        :       null;
}
```

}

It's basically a User entity, so I've removed unnecessary code.

In UsuariosForm:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Form\Usuarios;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
class UsuariosForm extends Form
{
public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
{
    parent::__construct('Usuarios');

    $this->setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'Application\Entity\Usuarios'));

    $this->add(array(
            'type'      =>      'Zend\Form\Element\DateTime',
            'name'      =>      'datacriacao',
            // 'required'   =>      false,
            'options'   =>      array(
                'label'     =>  'Created At',
                'format'    =>  'Y-m-d H:i:s'
                ),
            'attributes'    =>  array(
                'class'     =>  'form-control input-sm',
                // 'min'    =>  Date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                // 'max'    => strtotime('+1 day',  Date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
                // 'step'       =>      1,
                )
            )
        );
```

I've tried with and without min, max and step on datacriacao. Inserting a record works just fine. This is my action to update the record:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Action to recover access.
 *
 * @access public
 */
public function recoverAccessAction()
{
    $recoverKey = $this->params('id', 0);

    $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

    $form = new UsuariosForm($entityManager);
    $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'Submit');

    $usuariosRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('Application\Entity\Usuarios');

    $usuario = $usuariosRepository->findOneBy(array('senhastatus' => 2, 'resetsenha' => $recoverKey ));

    $validationMessages = array();

    if (isset($usuario))
    {
        if ($this->request->isPost())
        {
            $data = $this->request->getPost();

            try {

                $hydrator = new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager, 'Application\Entity\Usuarios');

                $validationMessages = $this->checkPassword($data['senha'], $data['conferirSenha'], $usuario->getdatanasc()->format('Y-m-d'));

                if (sizeof($validationMessages) == 0)
                {
                    $data = $hydrator->extract($usuario);

                    $data['datanasc'] = $usuario->getdatanasc()->format('Y-m-d');
                    // $data['datacriacao'] = new \DateTime($usuario->getdatacriacao());
                    $form->setData($data);

                    var_dump($form->isValid());

                    if ($form->isValid())
                    {
                        $stringHelper = new StringHelper();
                        $salt = $stringHelper->generateRandomString();
                        $senha = md5($data['senha'].$usuario->getSalt());
                        $usuario->setSenha($senha);
                        $usuario->setdatacriacao(new \DateTime($usuario->getdatacriacao()));

                        $entityManager->persist($usuario);
                        $entityManager->flush();

                    }
                    else
                        print_r($form->getMessages());

                }
                else
                {
                        // Exibindo todas as mensagens de erro 'anexadas' aos campos
                    foreach ($validationMessages as $key => $messages) {
                        foreach ($messages as $key => $message) 
                            $form->setMessages(array($messages[0] => array($message) ));
                    }

                    print_r($form->getMessages());
                }

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // todo @gustavo: implement
            }

        }

    }
    return array('form' => $form, 'usuario' => $usuario);
}
```

Into the insert action, i just do this:

```
$usuario->setdatacriacao(new \DateTime('now'));
```

If i have to set any value, it would be easy as this:

```
$usuario->setdatacriacao($usuario->getdatacriacao()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

**Edit:**

When update the record, this happens:

```
Array ( [datacriacao] => Array ( [dateStepNotStep] => The input is not a valid step ) )
```

You can notice than i'm not doing nothing with this column when updating. And it shouldn't have anything changed: I just want to update some columns, not all of it! Sooo... the main problem here is: why this ZF2 can't handle datetime as easy as it would be? If insert works fine, why updating it is giving me this nightmare?

**Edit #2:**

Actually, isn't working anymore into insert. What is with this thing?

Error:
Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /home/inhotim/Trabalho/0-OPE/scape/ProduÃ§Ã£o/Web/scape/vendor/zendframework/zend-validator/src/DateStep.php on line 220

```
Value setted:
'datacriacao' => 
    object(DateTime)[500]
      public 'date' => string '2015-08-14 16:18:28' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'America/Sao_Paulo' (length=17)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is exactly the problem? What is happening on update? You have not described it.

Comment: DateTime issue ([dateStepNotStep] => The input is not a valid step ) when updating record
It's on the title of the post.
More detailed: Array ( [datacriacao] => Array ( [dateStepNotStep] => The input is not a valid step ) )

Comment: Can you post the filter and validator for "datacriacao" and also the form value received from the browser for this field?

Comment: Actually, i don't have any validator for this field, the 'official' documentation don't supply any of:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.element.date.time.html
Googling it didn't help, either.

Comment: And: The value received from the browser is below Edit #2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the default of DateTime element is a 1 min step and it sends it to the validator. So if the seconds is not zero it would throw an error. Try with 00 seconds and check if it goes away. Else you need to set the step option to 'any'.

Comment: You don't believe how I was going insane because of this 'simple' solution. Just setting step to any and removing min and max was the solution. Thanks.

PS: where did you found this 'any' option? I've been searching web for like 3 days ago, and nothing... :S

Comment: Source code my friend.. Not everything can be documented in a huge framework!

https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Element/DateTime.php#L136

Comment: I'll be honest. I did look into source code, but not that deep.

Again, thanks!